# grep between multiple pattern

Tags: awk, grep

Here is a (real-world) text:

```
<tr>
randomtext
ip_(45.54.58.85)
randomtext..
port(randomtext45)
randomtext random...
</tr>
<tr>
randomtext ran
ip_(5.55.45.8)  
randomtext4
port(other$_text_other_length444)
</tr>
<tr>
randomtext
random
port(other$text52)
</tr>
```

output should be:

```
45.54.58.85 45

5.55.45.8 444
```

I know how to grep 45.54.58.85 and 5.55.45.8

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="<tr>"}1' file | grep -oP '(?<=ip_\()[^)]*'
```

how to grep port taking into account that we have random text/length after port( ?

I put a third record that should not appear in the output as there is no ip

Comment: hi Avinash; 45.54.58.85 45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through `GNU awk` , `grep` and `paste`.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ RS="<tr>"}/ip_/{print;}' file | grep -oP 'ip_\(\K[^)]*|port\(\D*\K\d+' | paste - -
45.54.58.85 45
5.55.45.8   444
```

**Explanation:**

- `awk 'BEGIN{ RS="<tr>"}/ip_/{print;}' file` with the Record Separator value as `<tr>`, this awk command prints only the record which contains the string `ip_`
- `ip_\(\K[^)]*` prints only the text which was just after to `ip_(` upto the next `)` symbol. `\K` in the pattern discards the previously matched characters.
- `|` Logical OR symbol.
- `port\(\D*\K\d+` Prints only the numbers which was inside `port()` string.
- `paste - -` combine every two lines.

Comment: pretty cool Konsolebox indeed and many thanx to you but the question was 'how to grep...', Avinash rocks again! Avinash,if possible, could you give a bit more details about your solutions

Comment: @blue_xylo sure just wait for some mins.

Comment: `grep` can never give the solution on its own and `awk` does the significant work. Actually, `awk` can work on its own and `grep` is only a redundancy but it's ok no worries :) Welcome.

Comment: The question may have been "how to grep", but the correct answer is "grep is not a verb, and in this case it's not the best tool".

Comment: Actually grep is a verb, it's an abbreviation for `Globally find a Regular Expression and Print` which is written `g/re/p` in `ed`. There is also a tool by the same name but that tools name came after the desired action and is just one approach to grep-ing :-). You're right, though, the tool `grep` has no useful part to play in solving this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using `GNU Awk`:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { RS = "<tr>" } match($0, /.*^ip_[(]([^)]+).*^port[(].*[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[)].*/, a) { print a[1], a[2] }' your_file
```

And another that's compatible with any Awk:

```
awk -F '[()]' '$1 == "<tr>" { i = 0 } $1 == "ip_" { i = $2 } $1 == "port" && i { sub(/.*[^0-9]/, "", $2); if (length($2)) print i, $2 }' your_file
```

Output:

```
45.54.58.85 45
5.55.45.8 444
```

Comment: thanx Konsolebox, we 've got only part of port info in your output

Comment: @blue_xylo I got a new version. I'll fix the old one.

Comment: +1, but this will fail to print the port if it happens to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `awk`

```
awk -F"[()]" '/^ip/ {ip=$2;f=NR} f && NR==f+2 {n=split($2,a,"[a-z]+");print ip,a[n]}' file
45.54.58.85 45
5.55.45.8 444
```

How it works:

```
awk -F"[()]" '              # Set field separator to "()"
/^ip/ {                     # If line starts with "ip" do
    ip=$2                   # Set "ip" to field $2
    f=NR}                   # Set "f" to line number
f && NR==f+2 {              # Go two line down and
    n=split($2,a,"[a-z]+")  # Split second part to get port
    print ip,a[n]           # Print "ip" and "port"
    }' file                 # Read the file
```

Answer (score 0):

WIth any modern awk:

```
$ awk -F'[()]' '
    $1=="ip_"   { ip=$2 }
    $1=="port"  { sub(/.*[^[:digit:]]/,"",$2); port=$2 }
    $1=="</tr>" { if (ip) print ip, port; ip="" }
' file
45.54.58.85 45
5.55.45.8 444
```

Couldn't be much simpler and clearer IMHO.